# How to persist bash history?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, cygwin, bashrc

I don't know if this is expected, but my history is not saved across sessions. This is to say, if I close the window, then when I open it again, the history is empty. How can I persist it across sessions ?

Here are the outputs of the commands you asked:

```
 set -o | grep history
history         on

$ grep -i history ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile ~/etc/bash.bashrc ~/etc/profile ~/.profile
/cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/car/.bashrc:# Make bash append rather than overwrite the history on disk
/cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/car/.bashrc:# History Options
/cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/car/.bashrc:# Don't put duplicate lines in the history.
/cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/car/.bashrc:# export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a"
grep: /cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/car/etc/bash.bashrc: No such file or directory
grep: /cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/car/etc/profile: No such file or directory
/cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/car/.profile:if [ "x$HISTFILE" == "x/.bash_history" ]; then
/cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/car/.profile:  HISTFILE=$HOME/.bash_history

$ ls -la ~/ | grep history -> no output

$ echo $HISTFILE 
~/.bash_history
$ echo $HISTSIZE
500
$ echo $HISTFILESIZE 
500
```

After the edits described in the answer below, I now get:

```
grep -i hist .bashrc
# Make bash append rather than overwrite the history on disk
shopt -s histappend
# History Options
# Don't put duplicate lines in the history.
export HISTCONTROL="ignoredups"
# (added) A new shell gets the history lines from all previous shells
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
# HISTIGNORE is a colon-delimited list of patterns which should be excluded.
```

I am still unable to have a history saved across sessions. I read the following questions:

- [Bash history loss when using histappend](https://superuser.com/questions/20900/bash-history-loss)
- [How to prevent Bash from altering history?](https://superuser.com/questions/302230/how-to-prevent-bash-from-altering-history)
- [What determines what shows up in the bash history command?](https://superuser.com/questions/536155/what-determines-what-shows-up-in-the-bash-history-command)
- [How do I keep my bash history across sessions?](https://superuser.com/questions/211966/how-do-i-keep-my-bash-history-across-sessions)
- [save bash history, regularly](https://superuser.com/questions/477045/save-bash-history-regularly)

None seemed to address my issue, including the answer below from the very person which had their question answered from the supposed duplicate.

Comment: Also see my question [here](http://superuser.com/questions/575479/bash-history-lost-on-reboot) and the questions it links to. Try the suggestions in them and ask again if you still have problems. In the emantime, voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: edit: set -o | grep history shows the history is on, echo $HISTFILE shows ~/.bash_history, echo $HISTSIZE and $HISTFILESIZE both show 500. But the history is still not persisted across sessions

Comment: The $HISTFILE is set to ~/.bash_history, but there is no .bash_history file in ~. How can this be ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add new information rather than commenting. Include the output of these commands: `set -o | grep history`, `grep -i history ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile  ~/etc/bash.bashrc ~/etc/profile ~/.profile` and `ls -la ~/ | grep history`.

Comment: Try setting a specific history file, add this line to your `~/.bashrc`: `export HISTFILE="~/history"`. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Is this still an issue? If it is, try adding the relevant lines to `~/.profile` istead of `.bashrc`. I'm not sure how cygwin is set up but it might be running login shells in which case `.bashrc` is ignored and `.profile` is read instead.

Answer (score 11):

OK I found out what's wrong.
I can't close the window, I have to type 'exit' for it to close gracefully.

Comment: You have answered your own question! This is great, but you should mark it as such, for others to know that you are not expecting any further answers.

Comment: Hard to say this is an acceptable answer - I've got the same issue and manually closing the window to save history is not a good idea. Often, I close the terminal window in other ways and would not like to loose it then.

Comment: same thing has been happening to me.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you exactly want to achieve with persistent history. Assume that you have several terminals (or terminal tabs) open, each running bash, with their own history. Which is the one which should be saved in the end?

Answer (score 8):

Well, it looks like your `~/.bashrc` does not have the necessary options. Make sure these lines are in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
# Make Bash append rather than overwrite the history on disk:
shopt -s histappend
# A new shell gets the history lines from all previous shells
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
# Don't put duplicate lines in the history.
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. See edit for an update of the new output result.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend this setup in your bash config. It saves each command into a file which is named the current date, i.e. bash-history-2020-10-29.log in the ~/.logs directory.

```
# Saving history to file
export PROMPT_COMMAND='if [ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ]; then echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S") $(pwd) $(history 1)" >> ~/.logs/bash-history-$(date "+%Y-%m-%d").log; fi'

export HISTSIZE=100000
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T  "
# Avoid duplicates
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups  
# When the shell exits, append to the history file instead of overwriting it
#shopt -s histappend

# After each command, append to the history file and reread it
export PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND$'\n'}history -a; history -c; history -r"
```

Then using this bash function allows on to query and sort by date for previously used shell inputs.

```
alias s='search'
search() {
   ls -rt ~/.logs/*.log | xargs grep -rnw "$1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more complete solution that persists your bash history locally, stores additional context (cwd, runtime, exit code, etc) and syncs it to your other computers, see [hishtory](https://github.com/ddworken/hishtory). I got frustrated with this exact problem and built it to hopefully make shell histories work better. It works by storing a separate copy of your shell history in a SQLite DB where the many quirks of bash history handling can't accidentally delete it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1150336)

Comment: It seems like this is self-promotion. Please read the article about [expected behaviour](https://superuser.com/help/behavior) here.

Comment: Sorry about that! I updated it to make my affiliation clear and to include the relevant details on how it works.